# Fazer contagem de amigos em comum usando LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, inner

Possuo as seguintes tabelas:

**usuarios**:

```
id | usuario | pnome | snome | foto
1  | Igor    | Igor  | Souza | perfil.png
2  | Alex    | Alex  | Khal  | foto.jpg
3  | Maria   | Maria | Silva | foto.png
```

**amizades**:

```
id | amigo1 | amigo2 | estatus (2 significa que são amigos)
1  | Igor   | Alex   | 2
2  | Igor   | Maria  | 2
3  | Maria  | Alex   | 2
```

Na tabela acima, `amigo1` é quem enviou o convite de amizade...

Eu preciso saber quais os amigos do usuário da página acessada (`$userPagina`) e as informações deles (`pnome, snome, foto`), até aí tudo bem, fiz a seguinte query:

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.pnome, u.snome, u.foto
FROM amizades a
INNER JOIN usuarios u
ON (u.usuario = a.amigo1 AND a.amigo1 <> '$userPagina') OR (u.usuario = a.amigo2 AND a.amigo2 <> '$userPagina')
WHERE (a.amigo1 = '$userPagina' OR a.amigo2 = '$userPagina') AND a.estatus = 2
```

Então, ao acessar `meusite.com/Alex` ele me retorna corretamente os seus amigos (Igor e Maria), porém, quero também saber quantos amigos em comum os amigos do Alex (`$userPagina`) tem com o usuário logado que acessou seu perfil (`$userLogado`), ou seja, quantos amigos em comum Igor e Maria possuem com o `$userLogado`. Então, tentei adicionando os seguintes dados na query:

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.pnome, u.snome, u.foto, COUNT(c.id) as comum
FROM amizades a
INNER JOIN usuarios u
ON (u.usuario = a.amigo1 AND a.amigo1 <> '$userPagina') OR (u.usuario = a.amigo2 AND a.amigo2 <> '$userPagina')
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM amizades WHERE (amigo1 = u.usuario AND amigo1 <> '$userLogado' AND estatus = 2) OR (amigo2 = u.usuario AND amigo2 <> '$userLogado' AND estatus = 2)) c ON (u.usuario = A.amigo1 OR u.usuario = A.amigo2)
WHERE (a.amigo1 = '$userPagina' OR a.amigo2 = '$userPagina') AND a.estatus = 2
```

Porém, ao acessar `meusite.com/Alex` novamente, é retornado apenas o erro:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'u.usuario' in 'where clause'
```

Mas eu não entendi o motivo desse erro, visto que estou identificando o `u.` no `INNER JOIN`... Como arrumar? E, minha lógica para esta contagem está correta?

Estrutura das tabelas:

**usuarios**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `usuario` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
      `pnome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `snome` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
      `foto` varchar(90) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id`, `usuario`, `pnome`, `snome`, `foto`) VALUES
(5, 'Igor', 'Igor', 'Souza', 'perfil.png'),
(4, 'Alex', 'Alex', 'Khal', 'foto.jpg'),
(3, 'Maria', 'Maria', 'Silva', 'foto.png');

ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
```

**amizades**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `amizades` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amigo1` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `amigo2` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `estatus` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `amizades` (`id`, `amigo1`, `amigo2`, `estatus`) VALUES
(10, 'Igor', 'Alex', 2),
(9, 'Igor', 'Maria', 2),
(8, 'Maria', 'Alex', 2);

ALTER TABLE `amizades`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `amizades`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=13;
```

Imagem de exemplo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela questão eu entendi que você quer todos os amigos em comum entre dois usuários.

```
SELECT u.usuario, u.pnome, u.snome, u.foto, COUNT(c.id) as comum
FROM amizades a
INNER JOIN usuarios u
ON (u.usuario = a.amigo1 AND a.amigo1 <> '$userPagina') OR (u.usuario = a.amigo2 AND a.amigo2 <> '$userPagina')
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM amizades WHERE (amigo1 = u.usuario AND amigo1 <> '$userLogado' AND estatus = 2) OR (amigo2 = u.usuario AND amigo2 <> '$userLogado' AND estatus = 2)) c ON (u.usuario = A.amigo1 OR u.usuario = A.amigo2)
WHERE (a.amigo1 = '$userPagina' OR a.amigo2 = '$userPagina') AND a.estatus = 2
```

Repare que dentro da sub-consulta que se encontra depois do LEFT JOIN você está usando u.usuario, que existe apenas fora desta consulta. Isso se chama uma variável de correlação (correlation variable) e no SQL você só pode utilizá-la se colocar a keyword LATERAL depois do LEFT JOIN e antes da sub-consulta. Isso só acontece se a sua sub-consulta estiver dentro da cláusula FROM.

Infelizmente o MySQL ainda não implementa a keyword LATERAL, então se você fizer uma sub-consulta dentro da cláusula FROM você não pode utilizar nenhuma variável de correlação, ou seja, nenhuma variável definida fora da própria sub-consulta. 
Mas como isso não se aplica a cláusula WHERE, você pode utilizar normalmente uma sub-consulta com variável de correlação nesta cláusula.

Vou mostrar um solução um pouco diferente, mais fácil de entender. Como você já tem a consulta que retorna todos os amigos de uma pessoa, basta achar todos os amigos do usuário logado, todos os amigos do usuário da página e ver quais estão nas duas tabelas. Isso seria muito fácil com o uso do INTERSECT, porém o MySQL não tem essa implementação. Então fiz uma interseção dos dois conjuntos com um IN na cláusula WHERE:

```
SELECT COUNT(conta.usuario) FROM (
  SELECT u.usuario, u.pnome, u.snome, u.foto
  FROM amizades a
  INNER JOIN usuarios u
  ON (u.usuario = a.amigo1 AND a.amigo1 <> 'Alex') OR (u.usuario = a.amigo2 AND a.amigo2 <> 'Alex')
  WHERE (a.amigo1 = 'Alex' OR a.amigo2 = 'Alex') AND a.estatus = 2 AND (u.usuario, u.pnome, u.snome, u.foto) IN (
    SELECT u2.usuario, u2.pnome, u2.snome, u2.foto
    FROM amizades a2
    INNER JOIN usuarios u2
    ON (u2.usuario = a2.amigo1 AND a2.amigo1 <> 'Igor') OR (u2.usuario = a2.amigo2 AND a2.amigo2 <> 'Igor')
    WHERE (a2.amigo1 = 'Igor' OR a2.amigo2 = 'Igor') AND a2.estatus = 2
  )
) conta;
```

Repare que uma consulta pega todos os amigos de Alex e a outra pega todos os amigos de Igor. Depois você agrupa de forma a pegar todos os amigos de Alex que estão (IN) na tabela dos amigos do Igor, obtendo todos os amigos em comum. Depois disso você utiliza o COUNT para saber quantos amigos existem nessa tabela de usuários que são amigos de Alex e de Igor.

Aqui então é a consulta que você quer, apresentando todos os amigos de Alex e quantos amigos em comum ele tem com você:

```
SELECT amc.usuario, amc.pnome, amc.snome, amc.foto, COUNT(a.id) as amigos_em_comum
FROM
(
  SELECT am.usuario as usuario, am.pnome, am.snome, am.foto, u.usuario as amigo
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT u.usuario as usuario, u.pnome as pnome, u.snome as snome, u.foto as foto
    FROM amizades a 
    INNER JOIN usuarios u 
    ON (u.usuario = a.amigo1 AND a.amigo1 <> 'Alex') OR (u.usuario = a.amigo2 AND a.amigo2 <> 'Alex')
    WHERE (a.amigo1 = 'Alex' OR a.amigo2 = 'Alex') AND a.estatus = 2
  ) as am, amizades as a, usuarios as u 
  WHERE (am.usuario = a.amigo1 OR am.usuario = a.amigo2) AND (u.usuario = a.amigo1 OR u.usuario = a.amigo2) AND am.usuario <> u.usuario AND u.usuario <> 'Igor'
  ORDER BY am.usuario
) as amc, amizades as a
WHERE (amc.amigo = a.amigo1 OR amc.amigo = a.amigo2) AND (a.amigo1 = 'Igor' OR a.amigo2 = 'Igor') AND amc.usuario <> 'Igor'
GROUP BY amc.usuario, amc.pnome, amc.snome, amc.foto
ORDER BY amc.usuario
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Coloquei Alex e Igor pois as pessoas que lerem a questão terão mais facilidade em testar. Mas no seu caso é só substituir Alex por $userLogado e Igor por $userPagina.

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem de exemplo para esclarecer minha dúvida

Comment: Ah sim, você quer os amigos em comum que o userLogado tem com cada amigo do usuário da página, é isso?

Comment: Exato! Isso mesmo! Mostrar as informações de cada amigo do usuário da página (pnome, snome, foto) e quantos amigos em comum com o `$userLogado`, que nesse caso seria 1

Comment: Ok, agora a consulta está do jeito que você perguntou! É só substituir José por $userLogado e Alex por $userPagina! Outro dia eu tento explicar a consulta...

Comment: Está funcionando, porém, ao acessar `meusite.com/Alex` ele lista o usuário `Maria` (corretamente), mas `amigos_em_comum` retorna 3 ao invés de 1 (1 pois entre eu (`Igor`) e `Maria` há apenas um amigo, que é o próprio `Alex`).

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39449/discussion-between-sergio-mucciaccia-and-igor).

Answer (score 0):

Coloca o u.usuario para ser resultado da primeira query

```
SELECT u.pnome, u.snome, u.foto, u.usuario, COUNT(c.id) as comum
FROM amizades a
INNER JOIN usuarios u
ON (u.usuario = a.amigo1 AND a.amigo1 <> '$userPagina') OR (u.usuario = a.amigo2 AND a.amigo2 <> '$userPagina')
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id FROM amizades WHERE (amigo1 = u.usuario AND amigo1 <> '$userLogado' AND estatus = 2) OR (amigo2 = u.usuario AND amigo2 <> '$userLogado' AND estatus = 2)) c ON (u.usuario = A.amigo1 OR u.usuario = A.amigo2)
WHERE (a.amigo1 = '$userPagina' OR a.amigo2 = '$userPagina') AND a.estatus = 2
```

note a primeira linha do select

Comment: Eu já estava buscando o usuário na query, porém havia esquecido de colocar ao passar pra pergunta. Desculpe pelo erro, já atualizei a query da questão.

Comment: Vacilei também, coloca o u.usuario na query que está dentro do left join, porque o 'on' não está achando ele pra compar

Comment: Se bem que cada vez que olho pra esse select ele me confunde mais shaushauhsuahsuhas acho que com a base de dados em mãos seria mais legal pra encontrar a solução pra essa logica

Comment: Então cara, também me confundo suahduasduhas, mas o exemplo das tabelas que uso na query são os mesmos mostrados na pergunta... Alterei a query dentro do `LEFT JOIN` para `(SELECT id, usuario FROM amizades...`, daí o erro muda para: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'usuario' in 'field list'`, e faz sentido, pois não há essa coluna na tabela `amizades`... Mas então como fazer isso? Kkkkk

Comment: Consegue exportar um sql dessas duas tabelas? ai eu simulo o banco aqui e testo as querys

Comment: Vou adicionar na pergunta o sql...

Comment: Pronto, pergunta editada com o sql das duas tabelas

Comment: To aqui testando algumas possibilidades

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem de exemplo para esclarecer minha dúvida